# Initialize expensive resource at start up of WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, initialization

I have a WCF service which need to initialize some expensive resources used for all incoming calls. Firstly I used a static variable to record its status, but the variable was reset on every call. Then I used a static service constuctor to init, but it got called on every incoming call. I tried to set InstanceContextMode to Single and PerSession, but neither of them worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting your InstanceContextMode to Single is definitely the way to go if you need access to these resources across ALL calls to the service.  What probably happened (just a guess) is your worker process is getting recycled, resulting in your initialization code have to run again when a new worker process is started.  If that is what is happening, then take a look at this document to configure your application pool to use auto-start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx

If this doesn't help then some additional details on how/where your initialization code is implemented would be helpful.